# Below is my query in ORACLE which is getting ORA-00917: missing comma error

Tags: oracle

```
create table host_details
(
  host_name varchar(200),
  cluster_name varchar(200),
  env_id int,
  stats varchar(30),
  primary_owner int,
  secondary_owner int,
  last_upadted date,
  location varchar(30),
  ip_address float(20),
  instance_name varchar(50),
  app_name varchar(50),
  comments varchar(200)
);


INSERT INTO host_details
    (host_name, env_id, stats, primary_owner, secondary_owner, location,
     ip_address, instance_name, comments)
  VALUES
    ('DOVXLRMGNP01', 9, 'Active', 1, 2, 'denver', 192.10.6.52, 'LRM_PROD',
     'Nothing');
```

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00917: missing comma

Answer (score 2):

I think your IP address field is a `float` and the value you are entering is incorrect.

Try the below, changed `ip_address` from `float` to `varchar(20)`

```
create table host_details (host_name varchar(200),cluster_name varchar(200),env_id int,stats varchar(30),primary_owner int,secondary_owner int,last_upadted date,location varchar(30),ip_address varchar(20),instance_name varchar(50),app_name varchar(50),comments varchar(200));

INSERT INTO host_details (host_name, env_id,stats, primary_owner, secondary_owner, location, ip_address, instance_name, comments) VALUES ('DOVXLRMGNP01',9,'Active',1,2,'denver','192.10.6.52','LRM_PROD','Nothing');
```

It worked on SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6049/1/0

Answer (score 2):

```
create table host_details
(
  ...
  ip_address float(20),
  ...
);
```

but you're trying to insert the value `192.10.6.52` into it. A floating-point value can have only one decimal point.

You need to store an IP address as a string-type, either `CHAR(15)` or `VARCHAR(15)`. Beyond the problem of multiple periods, a `float` is meant to store an *approximate* value, while an IP address is an *exact* value.